# regex devide city

Tags: php, regex

I get these strings:

- Prieelstraat 7 - 1730 Asse
- Meuleken 10 - 9961 Boekhoute (Assenede)
- Burgemeester Vercruysselaan 6 - 8500 Kortrijk

The first word is the name of the street, but the name of the street can have multiple words, then followed by a digit (house nr), followed by - and then the zipcode, after the zipcode comes the name of the city.

How can I do this regex in PHP?

Comment: You just want to extract the city? Is the zipcode always numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will populate the $matches array with:

```
$matches[0] = full string
$matches[1] = street name
$matches[2] = house number
$matches[3] = zip code
$matches[4] = city
```

code:

```
preg_match('/^(\D+) (\d+) - (\d+) (\D+)$/',$input, $matches);
```

Comment: I just want address - zipcode - city, the house nr is not required, and it is causing problems because it has for example 3a (so not matching (d+), /^(.*?) - (\d+) (\D+)$/ fixed it

Comment: instead of (.*?)  you could try ([\d\w]+)   that will match only letters and numbers.  Either will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$address = 'Burgemeester Vercruysselaan 6 - 8500 Kortrijk';

$matches = array();
preg_match('/^(\D+)\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)\s*(.*)$/', $address, $matches);

print_r($matches);

/* output:

Array
(
    [0] => Burgemeester Vercruysselaan 6 - 8500 Kortrijk
    [1] => Burgemeester Vercruysselaan 
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 8500
    [4] => Kortrijk
)

*/
```

If the zip code can contain numbers, letters and dashes, change the last:

`(\d+)\s*`

to:

`([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\s+`